# Run a .bat file without user credentials in Windows? (or unchanging credentials)

Tags: batch-file, credentials

our company has a remote server in which we run the Task Scheduler to run .bat files.

Seems like it asks for user credentials usually, so I put in my own user/ password for this remote server to run these .bat scripts.

However, this seems like poor practice. Yesterday for the first time in 3 years, we had to change our Windows passwords. Lo and behold, the .bats that ran on the same old user/ pass silently failed (returned login error but that's only in the scheduler).

Any way to get around this? Schedule fail alerts? Not require a user or somehow have a constant service account that doesn't have password change?

Comment: Create a new account, call it "batch scripts" or something, give it whatever privleges the scripts need, and use it's credentials. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13951

Comment: I agree with Nephi. Where I work we have service accounts for tasks like that and those accounts are only allowed to login to specific computers.